# On cokernel via localization of morphism of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, free-modules

This might need only a simple argument, but I simply cannot wrap my head around it.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $S$ a multiplicative subset with a distinguished element $c \in S$, and $A$ and $B$ be $R$-modules ($B$ can be assumed to be free and even of finite rank if this is necessary). Consider the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
B @> \psi >> A @> \phi >> B \\
& @V  V V @VV  V\\
& & S^{-1} A @>> S^{-1} \phi > S^{-1} B
\end{CD}
with $S^{-1} \phi$ surjective (in fact $S^{-1} \psi \circ S^{-1} \phi$can be assumed surjective if necessary) and $\phi \circ \psi$ is multiplication by $c$.

I need to show that the cokernel of $\phi$ is annihilated by $c$. In other words that
$$\text{coker} \, \phi \subset \text{ker} (\phi \circ \psi).$$

I have a hard time understanding how the surjectivity of the localized map relates to the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "annihilated by $c$"? You mean any element of the cokernel is killed by some power of $c$ or just $c$? If you mean the former, you can just use the definition of localization to see this.

Comment: @YangPei Well, it's really a small claim from an article. I thought the author would mean killed by $c$ itself, not just some power.